# What does the code line if board [i][j]==0 do?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So I found this code online because I wanted to make my own so I like tried to understand what this person was doing by looking what all the different lines do, but i came across this line and I don't know what it does. I can't really find anything on this online, mostly because i don't know how to look it up or what it's called. It's a piece of code from the game connect 4, and this is the function for drawing the circles. I'm talking about the

```
if board[i][j]==0:
```

and

```
if board[i][j]==1:
```

code. It's in this little function:

```
def draw_pieces(): #draws the pieces
    global board #makes 'board' global
    row_gap = HEIGHT/ROWS #variable row_gap is now 771,4 / 6 = 128,6 (gap between circles)
    col_gap = WIDTH/COLS #variable col_gap is now 900 / 7 = 128,6 (gap between circles)
    Y = STARTY + row_gap / 2; # Y is now -385,7 + 128,6 / 2 = -321,4 
    for i in range(ROWS): #this next function happens 6 times (i think its first black their turn)
        X = STARTX + col_gap/2 #X is now -450 + 128,6 / 2 = -385,7
        for j in range(COLS): #this next function happens 7 times (then red their turn)
            if board[i][j] == 0: #if board i and j are equal to 0??
                draw_circle(X,Y,row_gap/3,'white') #draw a circle on X and Y, radius row_gap/3 and in color white
            elif board[i][j] == 1: #if board i and j are equal to 1??
                draw_circle(X,Y,row_gap/3,'black') #draw a circle on X and Y, raduis row_gap/3 and in color black
            else: #if board i and j are equal to anything else??
                draw_circle(X,Y,row_gap/3,'red') #draw a circle on X and Y, radius row_gao/3 and in color red
            X += col_gap #for every j, X is now added with col_gap (128,6)
        Y += row_gap #for every i, Y is now added with row_gap (128,6)
```

excuse all my comments on every line, I'm trying to understand the code. If someone can help me with this (or share a website or doc that explains it) that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists (more broadly https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the [source and illustration of this game from pythonturtle.academy](https://pythonturtle.academy/connect-4-with-python-turtle-source-code-included/) we can see more clearly what the code does:

[image]

The two dimensional `board` matrix stores one of three values, 0 for `'white'` or unoccupied, 1 for `'black'`, the 1st player and 2 for `'red'`, the 2nd player.  So the code in question is drawing circles on the board whose color is based on who occupies, (or doesn't occupy) the row and column, `[i][j]`, in question:

```
if board[i][j] == 0:
    draw_circle(X,Y,row_gap/3,'white')
elif board[i][j] == 1:
    draw_circle(X,Y,row_gap/3,'black')
else:
    draw_circle(X,Y,row_gap/3,'red')
```

The `else:` clause is an implicit `elif board[i][j] == 2:`